# Constructing (but not destucting) an object of a class with a deleted or non-user-provided private destructor

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

Is the following snippet of code well-formed?

```
struct A { ~A() = delete; };
A *pa{new A{}};

class B { ~B() = default; };
B *pb{new B{}};
```

At a first glace it would seems as if the deleted dtor of `A` and the private explicitly-defaulted dtor of `B` are never used (intentional memory leak, if you will), which would arguably imply that it is well-formed.

Clang accepts the program for various compiler and C++ versions (C++11 through C++2a).

GCC, on the other hand, rejects the program for various compiler and C++ versions.

> ```
> struct A { ~A() = delete; };
> A *pa{new A{}};  // GCC error: use of deleted function 'A::~A()'
>
> class B { ~B() = default; };
> B *pb{new B{}};  // GCC error: 'B::~B()' is private within this context
> ```

<sub>(It if well-formed; before I file a bug report: Is there any open GCC bug report for this corner case? I've searched GCC:s bugzilla myself to no avail.)</sub>

---

Peculiarly GCC accepts the case of a private *user-provided* destructor:

```
class C { ~C(); };
C *pc{new C{}};  // OK

class D { ~D() {} };
D *pd{new D{}};  // OK
```

which could hint for some GCC doing something special for aggregate classes, as `A` and `B` are aggregates whereas `C` and `D` are not. However GCC is no consistent with this behaviour, as the following example

```
struct E {
    ~E() = delete; 
private: 
    int x;
};
E *pe{new E{}};
```

where `E` is not an aggregate (private data member) is likewise rejected like the for the aggregate classes `A` and `B` above, whereas the examples of `F` and `G` below (an aggregate until C++20, and a non-aggregate, respectively)

```
struct F {
    F() = default;
    ~F() = delete; 
};
F *pf{new F{}};

struct G {
    G() = default;
    ~G() = delete; 
private: 
    int x;
};
G *pg{new G{}};
```

are both accepted by GCC.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Eric ”Is there any open bug report [...]” (that I have obviously failed to find), or an answer pointing out that I am wrong and that this example, for some reason, is actually ill-formed.

Comment: If a constructor throw, then the compiler need to destruct what has already be done... Not sure if the standard specify those cases. Have you tried to specify ˋnothrow`? Also, are your classes so simple?

Comment: @cigien Added LL tag.

Comment: See http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#8 . Although an aggregate class isn't one of its own elements, perhaps this is where gcc is getting confused,

Comment: @ecatmur That might be relevant, thanks. GCC is quite inconsistent, though, in its rejection of the examples as per above w.r.t. the example class being and aggregate or not (I expanded my answer with a few more examples).

Comment: @Phil1970 -- you're right that if the constructor throws an exception, the compiler has to unwind any parts that have already been constructed. That doesn't involve the destructor of the object being constructed; that destructor can only be used after successful construction (think about what you'd have to do to write a destructor that could deal with a partially-constructed object). The compiler generates code that keeps track of what has been constructed so far, so that it can destroy only the parts that have been successfully constructed.

Comment: Is this https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87066 / https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59238 ?

Comment: @JeffGarrett That looks like it, particularly [59238](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59238), thanks. I guess we may argue, out of "common C++ sense", that this is indeed a GCC bug, but it would be nice to have a normative motivation for it.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Thanks, I think I found the relevant standard passages (and posted a self-answer with them) that would agree with the bug report [59238](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59238).

Comment: Nice. Have an upvote. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The snippets are well-formed; this is a GCC bug ([59238](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59238))

To begin with, [[class.dtor]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#4.sentence-3) explicitly mentions that the *selected destructor* for a given class may be deleted:

> At the end of the definition of a class, overload resolution is performed among the prospective destructors declared in that class with an empty argument list **to select the destructor for the class, also known as the *selected destructor***. [...] **Destructor selection does not constitute** a reference to, or **odr-use** ([basic.def.odr]) **of, the selected destructor**, and in particular, **the selected destructor may be deleted** ([dcl.fct.def.delete]).

[[class.dtor]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#15) governs for which cases a destructor is invoked implicitly; starting with the first part:

> A destructor is invoked implicitly
>
> - *(15.1)* for a constructed object with static storage duration ([basic.stc.static]) at program termination ([basic.start.term]),
> - *(15.2)* for a constructed object with thread storage duration ([basic.stc.thread]) at thread exit,
> - *(15.3)* for a constructed object with automatic storage duration ([basic.stc.auto]) when the block in which an object is created exits
>   ([stmt.dcl]),
> - *(15.4)* for a constructed temporary object when its lifetime ends ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]).
>
> [...] A destructor may also be invoked implicitly through use of a
> *delete-expression* ([expr.delete]) **for a constructed object allocated by a *new-expression*** ([expr.new]); **the context of the
> invocation is the *delete-expression*.**

None of *(15.1)* through *(15.4)* applies here, and particularly "for a constructed object allocated by a *new-expression*", which does apply here, a destructor is invoked implicitly only through the use of a *delete-expression*, which we are not using in this example.

The second part of [[class.dtor]/15](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#15) covers when a destructor is *potentially invoked*, and that a program is ill-formed if a destructor is potentially invoked and is deleted:

> A destructor can also be invoked explicitly. A destructor is **potentially invoked if it is invoked or as specified in [expr.new], [stmt.return], [dcl.init.aggr], [class.base.init], and [except.throw].**
> A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context of the invocation.

No destructor is invoked explicitly in this case.

[[expr.new]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new) (particularly referring to [[expr.new]/24](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#24)) does not apply here, as it relates only to when creating an array of objects of class type (using a *new-expression*).

[[stmt.return]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return) does not apply here, as it relates to (possible) invocation of constructors and destructors in return statements.

[[dcl.init.aggr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr) (particularly [[dcl.init.aggr]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#8)) does not apply here as it relates to the potentially invoked destructors of the *elements* of the aggregate, and not a potentially invoked destructor of the aggregate class itself.

[[class.base.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init) does not apply here as it relates to potentially invoked destructors of (base class) subobjects.

[[except.throw]](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw) (particularly [[except.throw]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#3) and [[except.throw]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#5)) does not apply here as it relates to the potentially invoked destructor of an *exception object*.

Thus, none of [class.dtor]/15 applies in this case, and GCC is wrong to reject the examples of `A`, `B` and `E` in the OP. As pointed out [in a comment by @JeffGarrett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124761/constructing-but-not-destucting-an-object-of-a-class-with-a-deleted-or-non-use#comment115145772_65124761), this looks like the following open GCC bug report:

- [Bug 59238 - Dynamic allocating a list-initialized object of a type with private destructor fails.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59238)

And we may note, as pointed out in the bug report, that GCC only wrongly rejects these program when allocating using list-initialization, whereas the following modified examples `A`, `B` and `E` are all accepted by GCC:

```
struct A { ~A() = delete; };
A *pa{new A()};

class B { ~B() = default; };
B *pb{new B()};

struct E {
    ~E() = delete; 
private: 
    int x;
};
E *pe{new E()};
```